# How I can get selected row from JTable and set it into JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextarea

How I can get selected row from `JTable` and set it into `JTextArea` to print all the data about the row?

Here is the part of my code:

```
 DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)jTable_S_Class.getModel();
   
    for(int row = 0;row<jTable_S_Class.getRowCount();row++)
    {
      
      row = jTable_S_Class.getSelectedRow();
String S_Hobby =jTable_S_Class.getValueAt(row,0).toString();
  String S_Phone =jTable_S_Class.getValueAt(row,1).toString(); 
   String S_Area =jTable_S_Class.getValueAt(row,2).toString();
   String S_Class_Name =jTable_S_Class.getValueAt(row,3).toString();
 String S_Mony=jTable_S_Class.getValueAt(row,4).toString();
    String S_Year  =jTable_S_Class.getValueAt(row,5).toString();
   String S_Student_Part =jTable_S_Class.getValueAt(row,6).toString();
   String S_Student_ID =jTable_S_Class.getValueAt(row,7).toString();
     String S_Statues=jTable_S_Class.getValueAt(row,8).toString();
  String S_Mother_Name=jTable_S_Class.getValueAt(row,9).toString();
String S_Student_Name=jTable_S_Class.getValueAt(row,10).toString();
 Print_Area.setText(Print_Area.getText()+S_Student_Name+"\t\n"+S_Mother_Name+"\t\n"+S_Statues+S_Student_ID +"\t\n"+S_Hobby+"\t\n"+S_Student_Part+"\t\n"+S_Year+"\t\n"+ S_Mony +"\t\n"+S_Class_Name +"\t\n"+S_Area +"\t\n"+S_Phone+"\n");
         
    }
     Print_Area.setText(Print_Area.getText()+"\n");
    Print_Area.setText(Print_Area.getText()+"==============================================================");
     Print_Area.setText(Print_Area.getText()+"\t\t    إدارة المدرسة\n");
     Print_Area.setText(Print_Area.getText()+"=============================================================\n");
   
           }
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data for the table. 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code. ..

Comment: .. 4) **See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)** I suggest that because taking data nicely formatted in a `JTable` and dumping it to a `JTextArea` seems to be .. counter productive. What is it that you are trying to offer the user by doing so?